# how to style legend.png on a react-native map view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to style a legend I created for a android map in my react-native project. I am having a hard time getting it to position correctly. Having to use the absolute property with the legend container threw me off.

[image: screenshot]

Styles

```
   container: {
    flex: 1
},
map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 56,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
},
legendContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 200,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    height: 65,
    width: 210,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
},
legend: {
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 60,
    width: 180,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    resizeMode: 'cover'
}
```

Map.js

```
 <View style= { styles.container } >
        <Toolbar
            title={this.state.selectedTrip.tripName || this.state.selectedTripName}  />
        <MapView
            style={styles.map}
            region={this.state.region}
            >
        </MapView>
        <View style={styles.legendContainer}>
            <Image source={require('../../img/legend.png') } style={styles.legend}/>
        </View>
    </View >
```

Comment: just add `resizeMode='contain'` as a property to your image, like `<Image source={require('../../img/legend.png') } style={styles.legend} resizeMode='contain' />` and not in its style

Comment: awesome! please put in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `resizeMode='contain'` as a property to your image and not in its style:

```
<Image 
  source={require('../../img/legend.png') } 
  style={styles.legend} 
  resizeMode='contain' 
/>
```

Reference: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode