# React native - scaling an image clips it instead

Tags: image, react-native

I have an image for my app, and it should cover the entire screen. It's a bit wide and tall, so I want to rescale it to fit the screen (never mind aspect ratio at the moment). However, the width and height I apply don't rescale the image, but rather clip it.

Here's my code:

```
render() {
    const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    const imageWidth = { width: width };
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
                style={styles.openingImage, imageWidth}
                source={require('./src/images/opening.jpg')}>
            </Image>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
    },

    openingImage: {
        resizeMode: 'cover',
    }
});
```

Why is it cliping instead of resizing?

Comment: try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37576063/1206613

Comment: Thanks... It took some extra-tweaking, but I got it to work...

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Answer (score 0):

Set both width and height of the `Image` to `undefined`

```
imageStyle: {
   width: undefined,
   height: undefined,
}
```